# How to improve the performance of a struts2 application?

Tags: java, multithreading, struts2, singleton

We have an application built in Struts2 framework. Actually it was a legacy application developed in strtus1 and migrated to Struts2.

We have observed that for certain request the server side takes more time to process. Also sometimes, the application also gives `OutOfMemoryError` for such requests.

Now, for struts2, I read that for each request, a new instance of action class is formed and it services the request. I wanted to understand, for service layer and DAO layer, how many instances of class are formed?

I think reducing these number of class instances can improve the performance and prevent the `OutOfMemoryError`.

Our application is deployed as 2 different war files of 2 different projects. I have inspected. I have observed that certain classes are present in both the projects.

So what should I do so that there is only one instance of such classes in Weblogic server. I read somewhere that such classes should be kept in weblogic lib folder. Is it true?

Basically, I am looking to reduce these class instances to improve performance.
Any suggestions to reduce them will be very much helpful.

Comment: Don't ever try to optimize something based on guessing. Profile your application to see what the real problems are, then fix them. "I think reducing these number of class instances can improve the performance" means "I don't know what I'm doing".